# generators vs basis of an algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology

> Are all bases of an algebra generating sets, but all generating sets are not bases?

A basis can only use addition and scalar multiplication to generate an algebra, which means it is a generating set. But can generating sets or generators that are not a basis use the vector product or actually need the vector product to generate the algebra?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generating sets are, in general, much smaller than bases.  For example, $\{X\}$ is a generating set for $\mathbb{R}[X]$, but to extend this to a basis we need all of $\{1,X,X^2,\ldots\}$.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^3$ as an algebra with the usual cross product can be generated by any two linearly independent vectors, but the basis must consist of three linearly independent vectors, right?

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis That's right, though be careful with the terminology since the term "algebra" may or may not imply associativity depending on the context.